# Angular - import module between two libraries

Tags: angular

I created two libries with [this](https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries) tutorial:

`ng new my-library --create-application=false
 ng generate library core
 ng generate library shared`

I would like to import CoreModule to SharedModule:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CoreModule } from '???';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CoreModule
  ],
  exports: []
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

In CoreModule is public-api.ts:

```
export * from './lib/core.module';
```

I tried edit projects/shared/tsconfig.lib.json:

```
"paths": {
      "library/core": ["../../dist/core/"],
    }
```

But when I run `ng build shared`:

> ERROR: projects/shared/src/lib/shared.module.ts(2,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'library/core'.
>   projects/shared/src/lib/shared.module.ts(8,5): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'CoreModule'.

What is right way to import modules between two libraries in the same workspace? Thanks

EDIT: tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "core": [
        "dist/core"
      ],
      "core/*": [
        "dist/core/*"
      ],
      "shared": [
        "dist/shared"
      ],
      "shared/*": [
        "dist/shared/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

core library tsconfig.lib.json:

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../out-tsc/lib",
    "target": "es2015",
    "declaration": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "types": [],
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2018"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "annotateForClosureCompiler": true,
    "skipTemplateCodegen": true,
    "strictMetadataEmit": true,
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "enableResourceInlining": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

shared library tsconfig.lib.json

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../out-tsc/lib",
    "target": "es2015",
    "declaration": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "types": [],
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2018"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "annotateForClosureCompiler": true,
    "skipTemplateCodegen": true,
    "strictMetadataEmit": true,
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "enableResourceInlining": true,

  },
  "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Your `import { CoreModule } from '???'` should have the path to the Core Module's `.module.ts` file. That should be enough to import it.

Answer (score 0):

No need to add `paths` in Shared `tsconfig.lib.json`. You just import with that library name what i did it here.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedComponent } from './shared.component';
import { CoreModule } from 'core';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [SharedComponent],
imports: [
    CoreModule
],
exports: [SharedComponent]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

In my tsconfig.json file look like below one.

```
"paths": {
  "core": [
    "dist/core"
  ],
  "core/*": [
    "dist/core/*"
  ],
  "shared": [
    "dist/shared"
  ],
  "shared/*": [
    "dist/shared/*"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I remove `paths` from tsconfig.lib.json and add import `import { CoreModule } from 'core'` to SharedModule. But when I run `ng build shared`, get this error: ERROR: error TS6059: File '/angular/library/projects/core/src/lib/core.module.ts' is not under 'rootDir' 'angular\library\projects\shared\src'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.

Comment: Your tsconfig.json as like below one.
`"paths": {
  "core": [
    "dist/core"
  ],
  "core/*": [
    "dist/core/*"
  ],
  "shared": [
    "dist/shared"
  ],
  "shared/*": [
    "dist/shared/*"
  ]
}
`

Comment: Yes my ts.config in library folder (root) is the same

Comment: did you build `ng build core` before `ng build shared`?

Comment: can you share your `tsconfig.json` and `tsconfig.lib.json`

`Note: tsconfig.json is the root tsconfig.json file`

Comment: Even i tried with your tsconfig file. It works fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

I find solution. Don't forget `umdModuleIds` in shared/ng-package.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
  "dest": "../../dist/common",
  "lib": {
    "entryFile": "src/public-api.ts",
    "umdModuleIds": {
      "core": "core"
    }
  }
}
```